# drawing part of open gl texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d, sprite-sheet

I am trying to draw only part of my sprite sheet. But it just scales the image and no drawing 1/3 of the width of the image. How can I crop the image so only 1/3 shows. Text is below ( ios 7,opengl es 2)- (GLKMatrix4) modelMatrix {

```
GLKMatrix4 modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelMatrix, x, y, 0);
return modelMatrix;

}
- (void)setSprite:(NSString *)fileName effect:(GLKBaseEffect *)newEffect {

// 1
self.effect = newEffect;

// 2
NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                              GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                              nil];

// 3
NSError * error;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil];

// 4
self.textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&error];
if (self.textureInfo == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return ;
}

TexturedQuad newQuad;
newQuad.bl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0);
newQuad.br.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.textureInfo.width, 0);
newQuad.tl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, self.textureInfo.height);
newQuad.tr.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.textureInfo.width, self.textureInfo.height);

newQuad.bl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 1);
newQuad.br.textureVertex = CGPointMake(1, 1);
newQuad.tl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0);
newQuad.tr.textureVertex = CGPointMake(1, 0);

self.quad = newQuad;

}

- (void)render {

// 1
self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

// 2
y++;
self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.modelMatrix;
[self.effect prepareToDraw];

// 3
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);


// 4
TexturedQuad q;
q.bl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 1);
q.br.textureVertex = CGPointMake(1, 1);
q.tl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0);
q.tr.textureVertex = CGPointMake(1, 0);
q.bl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0);
q.br.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.textureInfo.width/3, 0);
q.tl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, self.textureInfo.height);
q.tr.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.textureInfo.width/3, self.textureInfo.height);
long offset2 =(long)&q;
//long offset = (long)&_quad;
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset2 + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset2 + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));

// 5
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

}

Update:
        TexturedQuad newQuad;
    newQuad.bl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    newQuad.br.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.textureInfo.width/3, 0);
    newQuad.tl.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(0, self.textureInfo.height);
    newQuad.tr.geometryVertex = CGPointMake(self.textureInfo.width/3, self.textureInfo.height);

```
newQuad.bl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 1);
newQuad.br.textureVertex = CGPointMake(.3, 1);
newQuad.tl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0);
newQuad.tr.textureVertex = CGPointMake(.3, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what texture coordinates are for.  Your 'textureVertex' is specifying the full dimensions of your texture (with 0.0 to 1.0) mapped to the quad.  You need to change some of those values to either 1/3 or 2/3.  For example:

```
newQuad.bl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0.33);
newQuad.br.textureVertex = CGPointMake(1, 1);
newQuad.tl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(0, 0.33);
newQuad.tr.textureVertex = CGPointMake(1, 0);
```

Comment: but should I store the entire texture then in the render method I draw a section of the main texture?

Comment: Yes, store the entire texture.  glTexSubImage2D() is not really much faster than glTexImage2D() anyway, on most embedded platforms.