# How to use part of a texture?

Tags: three.js

How do I create a three.js material/geometry which uses part of a texture?

I am first rendering a scene to a texture. This texture is used for a `Mesh` with a `CubeGeometry` and a `MeshLambertMaterial`. What I would like to do now is have only a part of the texture displayed on the cube face (like a window into the texture).

*I've done this before using OpenGL ES directly, with shaders, but I don't see what parameters might make it possible using the standard three.js library.*

Answer (score 0):

That is what texture coordinates are for. See this question and answer:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366991/drawing-part-of-open-gl-texture/19367844#19367844
```

Comment: Yes, I know that in OpenGL/others. I'm looking for how to do this with three.js.